# Get specified texts in a div, than search for them in a different div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get texts from a div, than i want to search for these titles on the same page, but in a different div. And if one of the title exist there, i want to put some text after it. I tried to do it, but i don't know what is the problem. Last time i tried it with this jquery code:

```
var cim = $.trim($('.hirblokk span.comments:contains("új")').parent(".hirblokk").children("h3").text());
jQuery.each(cim, function(X) {
    $("ul.s_hir.show li.hir a:contains(X)").find("small").append(" (Új!)");
    return (this == cim.length);
});
```

As you can see i put the texts what i wanted to 'cim'(it is working). Than i tried (line 3) to check if one of the  'ul.s_hir.show li.hir a' contains one of the text, and if it containes, i put (append) something in the small tag (there is a small tag inside a tag : Text..)(this is not working). I tried it in more ways, but none of them worked.
If i write:

```
$("ul.s_hir.show li.hir a:contains(a)").find("small").append(" (Új!)");
```

than it will put ' (Új)' after every *small* tag when the *a* contains a character. So it looks like the problem is how i want to check if it *a* contains one of the text.
Oh, and i can get more than whan text for example: 'I am new' and 'Oh, hello darling' and only one of them contains *ul.s_hir.show li.hir a*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I have fully understood what text you want to search, but I see several problems:

- your cim var is a single string: as jQuery docs explains, *the result of the .text() method is a string containing the combined text of all matched elements* http://api.jquery.com/text/ . So if you have multiple elements matched with your selector, cim will be a string of all text concatenated.
- jQuery.each() iterate on each character of cim, and X is the index of the character in the string, not the value
- in your third line, X is not evaluated as a var because it's in double quotes.
- I don't understand what you're expecing with `return (this == cim.length)` : you're comparing a number (cim.length) with a string (the value of each currently evaluated).

Try something like this:

```
// titles contain all the h3 elements you're searching
var titles = $('.hirblokk  span.comments:contains("új")').parent(".hirblokk").children("h3"));
// you're iterating on each title
jQuery.each(titles, function(index,title) {
  // you're searching links elements containing each title text
  var text = $.trim($(title).text());
  $("ul.s_hir.show li.hir a:contains("+text+")").find("small").append(" (Új!)");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer, i tried it and it is working ! :) There are some little mistakes but who cares, i can delete some character :)  Thanks again !